# How to reorder places in char array

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, swap

I get problem with this `lines[k] = lines[k+1];`

Here is what I try to do:

```
char lines[MAXLINES][BUFSIZ];    
   for(k = 0;k < i;k++){
      char * tmp = lines[k];
      lines[k] = lines[k+1];
      lines[k+1] = tmp;
      change = 1;
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this? I just want to swap lines[k] with lines[k+1] in the array...

Comment: Are you sure that you want `for(k = 0;k < i;k++){` and not `for(k = 0;k < i - 1;k++){`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to arrays, you need `strcpy()`

```
char lines[MAXLINES][BUFSIZ]

for (int k = 0 ; k < i ; ++k)
 {
    char tmp[BUFSIZ];
    strcpy(tmp, lines[k]);
    strcpy(lines[k], lines[k + 1]);
    strcpy(lines[k + 1], tmp);
    change = 1;
 }
```

since `lines[k]` is an array, you can't assign to it but you can copy the contents of `lines[k]` to a temporary buffer, then copy the contents of `lines[1 + k]` to `lines[k]` and finally copy the contents of `tmp` to `lines[1 + k]`.

Comment: Aha, thanks for explanation,,, I am new to C so it's little bit confusing thing with arrays.

Comment: Though using non contiguous memory (array of pointer to array) would probably be a better fit here, as it would avoid the need to copy.

Comment: @DanielJour absolutely right, but dynamic allocation can be tricky if you don't have experience.

Comment: He yould use an index-array which hold pointers to the lines in the original array and perfoma all accesses through these. Same memory footprint as @DanielJour's approach, but no dynamic memory.